# Search Work Items Query

Tags: tfs

After using the 'Search Work Items' plugin for TFS 2010, I am struggling with the seeming limitations of the similar tool in TFS 2012.

My teams use this ad-hoc query to quickly search across **all** team projects to find work items based on a number of fields.  I have been unable to find a way to modify the query to search additional fields and remove the @Project limitation.  In TFS 2010 using the "--Template" string to open and modify the query was the ticket.  Is there a similar solution in TFS 2012?

It is possible to manually specify all the extra fields every time using the [search syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668120.aspx) (painful) - but how to *remove* limitations such as @Project etc?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to open a query in Team Explorer and remove the @project designation. You however will not be able to remove the @project limitation from the search box now on the TFS 2012 Web Access UI as it will only search across a single Team Project.

I would recommend that you read:

- http://blog.hinshelwood.com/project-of-projects-with-team-foundation-server-2010/
- http://blog.hinshelwood.com/one-team-project/

I think as you go forward you will find more and more that you are running into the Team Project boundary.

Comment: I understand that I have control of my own custom queries.  My question was regarding the search work items function and the ability to edit the query behind it.  It appears to have been removed in 2012, leaving any hard coded assumptions (such as the @Project specification) unchangable.  Also, I am using the thick client rather than Web Access

Comment: I do not know which search function you are referring to? There was never search for work items as par of Visual Studio 2010! There is however Search built in at the top of Team Explorer 2012 but it does not go across team projects.

Comment: Is not possible in 2012... the expected usage pattern for TFS is to have large team projects that encompass wider amounts of work...

Comment: I understand :) I would point out that this has been a recommended practice since TFS 2005/2008 and they have not changed anything only added features. I do however understand that this was not widely know as best practice untill 2010. Were you not using a third party plugin for search? Do they not still provide a solution?

Comment: I am using the third party 'Search Work Items' plugin.  They indicated that it had been 'integrated' into TFS 2012 and as such they no longer offer a solution outside of 2010.  In 2010, simply typing '--template' into the search box opened the query for editing.  Since they indicated the feature was in 2012, I expected similar functionality.  I think MS may have missed a major use case where SE managers may have to manage across multiple product teams - The ad-hoc queries my PM's, BA's and SE managers get with the 2010 version of the tool have become a favorite feature and add alot of value.

Comment: Any chance the implementation uses the stadard .wiq format - and if so, a way to find and manually edit the file?